# python Convert Encoding:LookupError: unknown encoding: ansi

Tags: python, character-encoding, codepages

Because my cdv file is encoded as `utf-8`, opening it with Excel will cause distortion, and when I then convert it to the standard `ANSI` encoding, I get this error:

code:

```
import chardet

def convertEncoding(from_encode,to_encode,old_filepath,target_file):
    f1=file(old_filepath)
    content2=[]
    while True:
        line=f1.readline()
        content2.append(line.decode(from_encode).encode(to_encode))
        if len(line) ==0:
            break

    f1.close()
    f2=file(target_file,'w')
    f2.writelines(content2)
    f2.close()



convertFile = open('4321.csv','r')
data = convertFile.read()
print chardet.detect(data)
if chardet.detect(data)['encoding']=='utf-8':
    convertFile.close()
    convertEncoding(chardet.detect(data)['encoding'], "ansi", "4321.csv", "4321_bak.csv")
```

error:

```
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/allenlee/Desktop/convert/convert.py", line 24, in <module>
    convertEncoding(chardet.detect(data)['encoding'], "ansi", "4321.csv", "4321_bak.csv")
  File "/Users/allenlee/Desktop/convert/convert.py", line 8, in convertEncoding
    content2.append(line.decode(from_encode).encode(to_encode))
LookupError: unknown encoding: ansi
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no `ansi` encoding in Python [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Choose appropriate encodings from following link: [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Answer (score 4):

OK,I find the answer.Thanks to @falsetru

```
#coding:utf-8

import chardet

def convertEncoding(from_encode,to_encode,old_filepath,target_file):
    f1=file(old_filepath)
    content2=[]
    while True:
        line=f1.readline()
        content2.append(line.decode(from_encode).encode(to_encode))
        if len(line) ==0:
            break

    f1.close()
    f2=file(target_file,'w')
    f2.writelines(content2)
    f2.close()

convertFile = open('1234.csv','r')
data = convertFile.read()
convertFile.close()

convertEncoding(chardet.detect(data)['encoding'], "utf-8", "1234.csv", "1234_bak.csv")
```