# How to drop rows from a pandas dataframe where any column contains a symbol I don't want

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `csv` file encoded in `ANSI` which I'm formatting with `python` `pandas` on a non `ANSI` machine. The resulting `dataframe`('df1') has some garbage in it.

```
Expirydate      food     color
20150713        banana   yellow
20150714        steak    brown
???             ???(g?0) ???
```

I am trying to remove the 'garbage' line using this:

```
df1[df1.Expirydate.str.contains("?")==False]
```

but am getting this error:

```
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Can anybody help? It would be most appreciated!

Comment: Can you post example of garbage values

Comment: a non-ansi machine? Python can read ansi, just load the csv data with `pandas.read_csv('filename', encoding='ansi')` or use python3, which solves all encoding problems automagically

Comment: I just tried that but got the following error `unknown encoding: ansi`. Also read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279413/python-convert-encodinglookuperror-unknown-encoding-ansi) that there is no ansi encoding in standard encodings. :-(

Comment: You're right. But according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences you are probably looking for an existing encoding, as ansi can mean many things, but your data is definately saved with a certain encoding. The link suggests to try 'cp1252'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `?` is treated as a regular expression. To actually match literal `?` in the content, you can escape it:

```
df1[df1.Expirydate.str.contains('\?')==False]
```

Comment: upvoted this answer :-) however it seems that it is still not able to pick up the 'garbage' line. I'm not sure whether it's because it can't handle regular expressions, even though escaped. Eventually I got around it by doing this `df1[~df1.Expirydate.str.contains('2015')]`.