# Data is stuck to a string format

Tags: python, pandas

All data I try to take from this database comes out as string even though I have selected change to number on the Excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib as plt
pdf= pd.read_csv('Campaign Feb 2023.csv', encoding="ANSI")
f= df["Total_Raised"]
x=int (f[3])
```

[image: Error screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data seems to contain numbers, where a comma (`,`) is used to mark the thousands. So `1,234,567` would be `1234567`. Python cannot interpret these commas. The best way is to tell pandas to convert the numbers when reading the files. For this use `thousands=','` as parameter of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('Campaign Feb 2023.csv', thousands=",")
```

Comment: Is the encoding parameter needed? This https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279431/9713633 says ansi is not supported in python

Comment: @billybud. Thanks. The other parameters are not mandatory here actually, the important one is "thousands" after all.